# How can I create IDataParameter in a function and return it?

Tags: c#

I don't know how this question is correct but my project condition is that I need a function that get value and parameter name and return a Parameter for using in some commands.

The prototype that I am thinking on it is like this :

```
public IDataParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, object value)
```

Is this anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nvoigt I created a class for it that derivative from IDBDataParameter

I added two constructor based on my requirement.

```
public class MyClass: IDbDataParameter
{
    public MyClass(string parameterName, object value)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        Value = value;
    }
    public MyClass(string parameterName, object value, DbType dbType)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        Value = value;
        DbType = dbType;
    }
    public DbType DbType { get; set; }
    public ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public bool IsNullable => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    public DataRowVersion SourceVersion { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public byte Precision { get; set; }
    public byte Scale { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

and use them in a method like this :

```
public IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, object value)
    {
        return new MyClass(parameterName, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly *can* do that, it would mean you'd need to hard code into your function *which* class you want to instantiate for your return value.

Better would be to pass in the commands, because *they* should know what type of parameter *they* need.

Example:

```
public IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(IDbCommand command, string parameterName, object value)
{
    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();

    parameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
    parameter.Value = value;

    return parameter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not have command parameter. I want to create parameters and then will send into another function.

Comment: So there is a project wide agreement on which provider you use and that providers implementation of IDataParameter has a public constructor you could use?

Comment: I found a solution for this. It seems it is working. I created a class that derivative from IdbDataparameter. I create constructor for this that get parameter name and parameter. Is it correct ?

Comment: I guess it's not wrong, you just need to make sure your provider (the command class) accepts it. Some may be picky and expect their own class to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will add a answer for it. ofcourse I do not know Stackoverflow accept it or give me negative point :-)